# "Neither-nor" as an adjective?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm reading in a newspaper:

> "He is a neither-nor judge."

Is the phrase correct?

Comment: Any"thing" can be a noun. (Almost) any noun can be used as a modifier. Where's the problem?

Comment: *neither-nor* is a loaded expression.

Comment: The usage has no meaningful level of currency. Whether it's "correct" or not is a matter of opinion, but I wouldn't bother even *having* an opinion unless you can cite the context. I've heard of someone being called [*an **either-or** person*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+either-or+person%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to mean they tend to see things in *absolute, black-and-white* terms. But I couldn't begin to guess what two things a *neither-nor judge* might conventionally be assumed to be rejecting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could it be someone who always finds a middle ground? Take it away from the context of a legal judge (guilty or innocent with no room for middle ground) and into the judging of a best cake competition and that might open some possibilities where it could describe someone who would never judge a cake as 'delicious' (the ultimate) and he would never judge a cake as 'unpalatable' (the worst), everything would fall into various degrees of 'nice'. The opposite of either-or.

Comment: @Frank I think your understanding matches the Google examples I've found, which I've listed in my answer below.

Comment: @Frank: In any given context, I guess it *could* mean that. But equally, it could mean *neither a "hanging judge" nor a bleeding-heart liberal*. Or anything else that fitted the context, but I really don't see any justification for supposing the usage has any inherent or established meaning, so it's just an invitation to post speculative answers *unless we have the exact context*. And even in *that* case, I think it's effectively a POB question, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Both grammatically and logically, this is fine.

Grammatically, this phrase is in parallel to structures such as *"a yes-and attitude"*, *"a potato-potahto disagreement"* or even *"a two-birds-one-stone situation"*.

As for the meaning (and thus also whether or not the phrase is logical), a quick glance through Google yielded such examples as:

> *"...that made him a “neither/nor” person (neither aristocratic nor plebeian, neither amateur nor specialist, neither reliant on patrons nor fully independent, etc.)"*
>
> *"a neither/nor person who is neither ethnic nor religious, neither affirmer nor denier of Jewishness or Judaism"*
>
> *"someone who falls between stable categories, a neither-nor person; neither leader nor colleague"*

All of these seem to imply that the person in question is the opposite of an either/or person (who tends to think in extremes or be characterised in such terms) - so a person that somehow fits in in the middle ground between two opposing viewpoints, skill levels, etc.

In your particular case, I imagine a *neither/nor judge* might be one that is, for instance, neither a Republican or a Democrat; or perhaps neither extremely pro-abortion or anti-abortion, etc etc.

That said, more context would be needed to properly decipher what the author actually meant in this particular case...

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically it is fine, but without more context it is hard to know what the columnist means by this. Perhaps the judge tries to find novel "win/win" outcomes for his or her cases rather than choosing one side over another - neither A nor B, but C.